# Почему List<E> воспринимается пустым несмотря на то, что в нём есть элементы?

Tags: java, сортировка, list, коллекции, arraylist

Class Sorter:

```
import java.util.*;


public class Sorter {
    private List<Detail> inputDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Sorter(List<Detail> inputList) {
        inputDetailsList.addAll(inputList);
    }

    private class MinTime1 implements Comparator<Detail> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Detail d1, Detail d2) {
            return d1.getT1() - d2.getT1();
        }
    }

    private class MinTime2 implements Comparator<Detail> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Detail d1, Detail d2) {
            return d1.getT2() - d2.getT2();
        }
    }

    private Detail getMinT1() {
        return Collections.min(inputDetailsList, new MinTime1());
    }

    private Detail getMinT2() {
        return Collections.min(inputDetailsList, new MinTime2());
    }

    public List<Detail> sort() {
        List<Detail> sortedDetailsList = new ArrayList<>(inputDetailsList);
        int i = 0, k = sortedDetailsList.size() - 1;
        for (ListIterator<Detail> iterator = inputDetailsList.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            if (getMinT1().getT1() <= getMinT2().getT2()) {
                sortedDetailsList.set(i++, getMinT1());
                inputDetailsList.remove(getMinT1());
            } else {
                sortedDetailsList.set(k--, getMinT2());
                inputDetailsList.remove(getMinT2());
            }
        }
        return sortedDetailsList;
    }

    public int getTime() {
        int time = 0;
        List<Detail> details = sort();
        for (Detail detail : details) {
            time += detail.getT1();
        }
        return time + details.get(details.size() - 1).getT2();
    }
}
```

Class Detail:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Detail {
    private int t1;
    private int t2;

    public Detail(int t1, int t2) {
        this.t1 = t1;
        this.t2 = t2;
    }

    public int getT1() {
        return t1;
    }

    public int getT2() {
        return t2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Detail: " +
                "t1 = " + t1 +", t2 = " + t2;
    }
}
```

Class Main:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Detail> details = new ArrayList<>();
        details.add(new Detail(1, 5));
        details.add(new Detail(6, 4));
        details.add(new Detail(2, 3));
        details.add(new Detail(6, 3));
        details.add(new Detail(9, 1));
        details.add(new Detail(4, 5));
        details.add(new Detail(2, 2));
        details.add(new Detail(7, 7));

        Sorter sorter = new Sorter(details);

        System.out.println(sorter.sort());

        **System.out.println(sorter.getTime());**
    }
}
```

При вызове из Main System.out.println(sorter.getTime()); вылетает ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 0
```

Comment: Неясно, что происходит с inputDetailsList за пределами метода sort, похоже что он просто становится пустым при первом вызове и при втором вызове sort сортировать нечего.

Comment: покажите, пожалуйста, весь код.

Comment: @Dred добавил весь код

Comment: @RuslanP.добавил весь код

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин В данном примере, у вас `inputDetailsList` равен нулю. Поэтому тут мы не получим ни size ничего

Comment: @Dred как это можно изменить?

Comment: А что происходит и что не так? Можете словами написать? И где класс, в котором все вызывается?

Comment: @defaultlocale добавил класс Main и обновил вопрос

Comment: sorter.sort() опустошает список inputDetailsList, вызов sorter.getTime() уже с пустым списком, т.к. также вызывает sort() внутри. Нужно как минимум использовать копию inputDetailsList внутри метода sort()

Comment: @RuslanP. я пытался сделать копию, но с ней тоже почему-то не работает. Всё уже перепробовал

Comment: У вас в цикле итератор не изменяется и никак не используется вообще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При каждом вызове `sort` возвращает новый список. Первый раз непустой, второй — пустой.

При первом вызове `sort` в процессе сортировки удаляет все элементы из входного списка (`inputDetailsList`).

```
if (getMinT1().getT1() <= getMinT2().getT2()) {
    sortedDetailsList.set(i++, getMinT1());
    inputDetailsList.remove(getMinT1()); //вот здесь
} else {
    sortedDetailsList.set(k--, getMinT2());
    inputDetailsList.remove(getMinT2()); //и вот здесь
}
```

Поэтому при втором вызове метод пытается отсортировать пустой входной список и получает пустой список в результате.

Пути решения:

- Следить за тем чтобы сортировка выполнялась только один раз (просто, но неудобно).
- Изменить алгоритм так чтобы он не изменял входной список.
- Копировать входной список перед сортировкой, так будет изменяться только копия.
- Хранить отсортированный список и при последующих вызовах `sort` возвращать готовый результат.

Также рекомендую изучить стандартные способы сортировки, вроде [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-).

Comment: В теории я всё это понимаю, а на практике не получается сделать ничего. Я создал новый метод, в котором создаю List<Detail> a = sort(); И пытаюсь потом работать с ним, но это не прокатывает

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин Не отчаивайтесь :) То, что ошибок много это хорошо, это говорит о том что Вы чему-то учитесь. Разбирайтесь с ними по одной и старайтесь их не повторять. Например, что именно не прокатывает?

Comment: locate в общем проблему я решил, сейчас покажу каким образом)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена благодаря ответу @default locate

```
public class Sorter {
    private List<Detail> inputDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
    **private List<Detail> sortedList;**

    public Sorter(List<Detail> inputList) {
        inputDetailsList.addAll(inputList);
    }

    private class MinTime1 implements Comparator<Detail> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Detail d1, Detail d2) {
            return d1.getT1() - d2.getT1();
        }
    }

    private class MinTime2 implements Comparator<Detail> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Detail d1, Detail d2) {
            return d1.getT2() - d2.getT2();
        }
    }

    private Detail getMinT1() {
        return Collections.min(inputDetailsList, new MinTime1());
    }

    private Detail getMinT2() {
        return Collections.min(inputDetailsList, new MinTime2());
    }

    public List<Detail> sort() {
        List<Detail> sortedDetailsList = new ArrayList<>(inputDetailsList);
        int i = 0, k = inputDetailsList.size() - 1;
        for (ListIterator<Detail> iterator = inputDetailsList.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            if (getMinT1().getT1() <= getMinT2().getT2()) {
                sortedDetailsList.set(i++, new Detail(getMinT1().getT1(), getMinT1().getT2()));
                inputDetailsList.remove(getMinT1());
            } else {
                sortedDetailsList.set(k--, new Detail(getMinT2().getT1(), getMinT2().getT2()));
                inputDetailsList.remove(getMinT2());
            }
        }
        **sortedList = new ArrayList<>(sortedDetailsList);**
        return sortedDetailsList;
    }

    public int getTime() {
        int time = 0;
        for (Detail detail : **sortedList**) {
            time += detail.getT1();
        }
        return time + **sortedList**.get(**sortedList**.size() - 1).getT2();
    }
}
```

Comment: В принципе должно сработать, хотя код не самый элегантный. Еще можно прямо в методе `sort` проверять, что если `sortedList` не null, то возвращать его и не выполнять сортировку. Так метод можно будет вызывать несколько раз безопасно.